# Is it possible for a Banach space to contain strictly its (continuous) dual

Tags: functional-analysis, dual-spaces

Is there an infinite-dimensional Banach space $X$ such that $X^{\star}\subsetneq X$ - i.e. $X^{\star}$ is proper subspace of $X$, both inheriting its linear and topological structure. For example $(c_0)^{\star}=l_1\subsetneq c_0$ however this inclusion is only linear, since these spaces have different topological structure (norms). I am not sure whether the problem is well-posed. Perhaps it turns out that if $X^{\star}\subseteq X$ then $X$ is Hilbert, so a strict inclusion is impossible.

Comment: Your $\subsetneq$ is necessarily given by a map because the spaces have elements of different nature. The question is; what kind of map do you want? An isometric isomorphism with its range? Yes, just take $\ell^2$, its dual is (isomorphic to) $\ell^2$, which you can put strictly inside itself using the right-shift operator: $(x_0,x_1,x_2,...)\mapsto (0,x_0,x_1,x_2,...)$. What else should the inclusion satisfy?